# Script de gestión de procesos

Tags: bash, script

amigos!! ^^
Necesito hacer un script que me gestione los procesos, sería algo así:

Crear un script en Bash que:

Debe recibir dos argumentos:
maxCPU: porcentaje máximo de uso de CPU.
maxMem: porcentaje máximo de uso de memoria.

Antes de comenzar se debe asegurar que los argumentos son correctos, comprobando lo siguiente:
Se indican los dos argumentos (si no es así, informar del error y devolver error: 100)
Ambos valores deben ser mayores o iguales que 0 (si no es así, informar del error y devolver error: 200)
maxMem debe ser menor o igual que 100 (si no es así, informar del error y devolver error: 150)

Si los argumentos son correctos, el script comprobará que el proceso del sistema que más porcentaje de CPU consume esté por debajo de maxCPU y el proceso del sistema que más porcentaje de memoria consume esté por debajo de maxMem. Esta comprobación se debe repetir cada 30 segundos de forma indefinida.

Si hay algún proceso que supere alguno de estos valores (si son los dos, elegir cualquiera de ellos), se mostrará información de dicho proceso y luego se imprimirá un menú para:
Ignorar el aviso y seguir comprobando
Disminuir en 3 puntos la prioridad del proceso
Interrumpir el proceso
Terminar el proceso
Finalizar inmediatamente el proceso
Detener el proceso ("congelarlo" de forma evitable)
Detener el proceso ("congelarlo" de forma INevitable)

Además, el usuario puede enviar señales al script en cualquier momento. El script tendrá el siguiente comportamiento según la señal que reciba:
Señal de interrupción: El script mostrará un mensaje: "Interrumpiendo ejecución" y se terminará el script con error=0
Señal de terminación: El script mostrará un mensaje: "Finalizando ejecución" y se terminará el script con error=0
Señal de usuario1: se mostrará la carga del sistema.
Señal de usuarios2: se mostrarán los límites de los procesos del sistema.
NOTA:  El comando ps tiene múltiples opciones para mostrar sólo la información que nos interesa, para ordenar la lista por diferentes criterios, etc. Investiga estas opciones para obtener el proceso con mayor uso de %CPU y el proceso con más uso de %MEM.

¿Me podéis ayudar? :)

Comment: Bienvenida. Qué intentaste?

Comment: Se te puede ayudar si muestras un [repro] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento, y el problema _específico_ que has tenido. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.